# Amcharts, categoryaxis and bullets

Tags: amcharts, bullet

I want to move a bullet on a categoryaxis after it's been created by setting the "category" prop. This works with dateAxis but not categoryaxis so I assume it's something wrong?

What happens when I use categoryAxis is that the prop gets updated but the bullet stays in its original place until I resize the window. Then the bullet moves to the new location specified by me. This tells me that something isn't updating as it should?
Please take a look at this codepen. Wait 1 sec and see that the bullet hasn't moved. Then resize the window and it moves.
    `Codepen`https://codepen.io/StaffMan/pen/ExjdyPy

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. Apparently you need to set categoryAxis.validateDataElement(range) manually. Then the bullet moves to its new location.